# Performing a redirect, when conversion / validation associated with query parameters fails

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

The following is a simple use case of `<f:viewAction>`.

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{testManagedBean.id}" maxlength="20"/>
    <f:viewAction action="#{testManagedBean.viewAction}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

The managed bean involved.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id; //Getter and setter.

    public void viewAction() {
        System.out.println("viewAction() called : " + id);
    }
}
```

The parameter `id` is passed through a URL. There is a conversion error, when a non-numeric value like `xxx` is passed through the URL in question and the `viewAction()` method associated with the listener of `<f:viewAction>` is not invoked.

The value of `id` is `null` in this case. I would like to redirect to another page, when `id` is not convertible to a desired target type (like in this case) or `id` is not validated against the specified validation criteria to avoid potential exceptions which are likely to be thrown in the [`LazyDataModel#load()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.3/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html#load(int,%20int,%20java.util.List,%20java.util.Map)) method of PrimeFaces or somewhere else in the associated managed bean whenever access to these parameters is attempted in the corresponding managed bean. For this to be so, the `viewAction()` method should be invoked.

How to proceed with this? Should I use

```
<f:event type="preRenderView">
```

in conjunction with `<f:viewAction>`?

Comment: At the moment, if `id` is `null`, the `viewAction` is not called?

Comment: No then it is called. It is invoked, for example if the URL looks like this, `www.example.com/abc.jsf?id=` (`id` is given no value here). It is not invoked, when the value of `id` supplied through a URL cannot be converted to `java.lang.Long` like so, `www.example.com/abc.jsf?id=xxx`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [specified](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr344/) behavior. When `PROCESS_VALIDATIONS` phase ends with a [validation failure](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isValidationFailed%28%29), both the `UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES` and `INVOKE_APPLICATION` phases are skipped. Exactly like as in "regular" forms with `<h:form>`. Think of `<f:viewParam>` as a `<h:inputText>` and a `<f:viewAction>` as a `<h:commandButton>` and it will become more clear.

For your particular requirement, performing a redirect when conversion/validation has failed, there are at least 3 solutions:

1. As you found out, add a `<f:event listener>`. I'd rather hook on `postValidate` event instead for better self-documentability.

   ```
   <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" maxlength="20" />
       <f:event type="postValidate" listener="#{bean.redirectIfNecessary}" />
       <f:viewAction action="#{bean.viewAction}" />
   </f:metadata>
   ```

   ```java
   public void redirectIfNecessary() throws IOException {
       FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

       if (!context.isPostback() && context.isValidationFailed()) {
           context.getExternalContext().redirect("some.xhtml");
       }
   }
   ```

   The check on `FacesContext#isPostback()` prevents the redirect being performed on validation failures of "regular" forms in the same view (if any).

   ---
2. Extend the builtin [`LongConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/convert/LongConverter.html) whereby you perform the redirect in `getAsObject()` (a validator is insuitable as the default converter for `Long` would already fail on non-numeric inputs; if a converter fails, the validators are never fired). This is however poor design (tight-coupling).

   ```
   <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" converter="idConverter" />
       <f:viewAction action="#{bean.viewAction}" />
   </f:metadata>
   ```

   ```java
   @FacesConverter("idConverter")
   public class IdConverter extends LongConverter {

       @Override
       public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
           if (value == null || !value.matches("[0-9]{1,20}")) {
               try {
                   context.getExternalContext().redirect("some.xhtml");
                   return null;
               }
               catch (IOException e) {
                   throw new FacesException(e);
               }
           }
           else {
               return super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
           }
       }

   }
   ```

   You could if necessary play around with `<f:attribute>` inside `<f:viewParam>` to "pass" parameters to the converter.

   ```
   <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" converter="idConverter">
       <f:attribute name="redirect" value="some.xhtml" />
   </f:viewParam>
   ```

   ```java
   String redirect = (String) component.getAttributes().get("redirect");
   context.getExternalContext().redirect(redirect);
   ```

   ---
3. Create a custom taghandler which does basically the same as `<f:event listener>` but without the need for an additional backing bean method.

   ```
   <html ... xmlns:my="http://example.com/ui">

   <f:metadata>
       <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.id}" maxlength="20" />
       <my:viewParamValidationFailed redirect="some.xhtml" />
       <f:viewAction action="#{bean.viewAction}" />
   </f:metadata>
   ```

   `com.example.taghandler.ViewParamValidationFailed`

   ```
   public class ViewParamValidationFailed extends TagHandler implements ComponentSystemEventListener {

       private String redirect;

       public ViewParamValidationFailed(TagConfig config) {
           super(config);
           redirect = getRequiredAttribute("redirect").getValue();
       }

       @Override
       public void apply(FaceletContext context, UIComponent parent) throws IOException {
           if (parent instanceof UIViewRoot && !context.getFacesContext().isPostback()) {
               ((UIViewRoot) parent).subscribeToEvent(PostValidateEvent.class, this);
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void processEvent(ComponentSystemEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException {
           FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

           if (context.isValidationFailed()) {
               try {
                   context.getExternalContext().redirect(redirect);
               }
               catch (IOException e) {
                   throw new AbortProcessingException(e);
               }
           }
       }

   }
   ```

   `/WEB-INF/my.taglib.xml`

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <facelet-taglib
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
       version="2.0"
   >
       <namespace>http://example.com/ui</namespace>

       <tag>
           <tag-name>viewParamValidationFailed</tag-name>
           <handler-class>com.example.taghandler.ViewParamValidationFailed</handler-class>
       </tag>  
   </facelet-taglib>
   ```

   `/WEB-INF/web.xml`

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
       <param-value>/WEB-INF/my.taglib.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```

   True, it's a bit of code, but it ends up in clean and reusable `<my:viewParamValidationFailed>` tag and is actually a good fit for a new [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) feature.

Comment: In the last example or in `<o:viewParamValidationFailed>`, is it possible to prevent a `@PostConstruct` method in a relevant view / request scoped managed bean from being executed, when conversion or validation fails? Sometimes, a `@PostConstruct` method is designed to invoke one or more business methods which execute expensive database calls quite unnecessarily even though conversion or validation fails.

Comment: @Tiny: No. Either use `<f:viewAction>` or check `isValidationFailed()`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply validate `id` yourself?

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    private String id;     //Getter and setter.
    private Long validId;  //Getter and setter.

    public void viewAction() {
        try {
            validId = Long.parseLong(id);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            String outcome = "redirect.xhtml";
            facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(facesContext, null, outcome);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the listener method, `viewAction()` itself is not invoked, when the value of `id` passed as a query-string parameter is not convertible to `java.lang.Long` like `xxx`. How could we then validate `id` in the `viewAction()` method? It would cause the `NullPointerException` in the `load()` method of PrimeFaces `LazyDataModel<T>`.

Comment: In my test case (Mojarra 2.2.6), `viewAction()` is always invoked. Note that I have changed the type of `id` to String.

Comment: Although I did not show the actual code to avoid code noise, `id` is actually converted to a JPA entity using a custom JSF converter. I'm currently using an additional `<f:event>` tag inside `<f:metadata>` (it may completely be unnecessary) to make a redirect in its listener method, whenever `id` is null. I will accept this answer a few days later, if no more answer(s) are added.