# JSF trying to create a TagHandler with a no-args constructor in a postback

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

According to the third option from BalusC's answer in this thread:

[Performing a redirect, when conversion / validation associated with query parameters fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23049930/the-listener-method-of-fviewaction-is-not-invoked-when-there-is-a-conversion-e)

I created the following solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd">
        <namespace>http://br.edu.ufca/web</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>viewParamValidationFailed</tag-name>
        <handler-class>br.edu.ufca.criacaoemail.ViewParamValidationFailed</handler-class>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>


public class ViewParamValidationFailed extends TagHandler implements ComponentSystemEventListener
{
    private final String _outcome;

    public ViewParamValidationFailed(TagConfig config)
    {
        super(config);
        _outcome = getRequiredAttribute("outcome").getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(FaceletContext context, UIComponent parent) throws IOException
    {
        if (parent instanceof UIViewRoot && !context.getFacesContext().isPostback())
        {
        ((UIViewRoot) parent).subscribeToEvent(PostValidateEvent.class, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void processEvent(ComponentSystemEvent event)
    {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (!context.isPostback() && context.isValidationFailed())
        {
            ConfigurableNavigationHandler navigationHandler =
                (ConfigurableNavigationHandler)
                context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            navigationHandler.performNavigation(_outcome);
        }
    }
}

    <f:metadata>
        <ufca:viewParamValidationFailed outcome="checarTipoEmailInformado" />
        <f:viewAction action="checarTipoEmailInformado" />
    </f:metadata>
```

When a URL is loaded the tag handler Works ok when there's a conversion error, but in a postback (wheter there's a conversion error or not) I get this exception:

```
08:21:37,809 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-25) UT005023: Exception handling request to /email-servidores/criacaoemail.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.InstantiationException: br.edu.ufca.criacaoemail.ViewParamValidationFailed
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.InstantiationException: br.edu.ufca.criacaoemail.ViewParamValidationFailed
    at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.restore(StateHolderSaver.java:153) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.restoreState(UIComponent.java:2633) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.restore(StateHolderSaver.java:165) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreAttachedState(UIComponentBase.java:1793) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreSystemEventListeners(UIComponentBase.java:1911) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1607) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.restoreState(UIViewRoot.java:1771) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:380) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1690) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:367) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:138) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:590) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:150) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:197) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: br.edu.ufca.criacaoemail.ViewParamValidationFailed
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.restore(StateHolderSaver.java:150) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: br.edu.ufca.criacaoemail.ViewParamValidationFailed.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3069) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:403) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    ... 48 more
```

As you can see JSF is trying to create the tag handler ViewParamValidationFailed calling a no-args constructor (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: br.edu.ufca.criacaoemail.ViewParamValidationFailed.()).

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: FYI: if you happen to use OmniFaces or can use OmniFaces 2.0 SNAPSHOT, you may find its `<o:viewParamValidationFailed>` more helpful: http://snapshot.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/viewParamValidationFailed

Comment: Apparently the problem was solved. I'm implementing SystemEventListener now. Thank you, BalusC. Unfortunately I can't mark your reply as answered.

Comment: Just upvote the duplicate answer if you found it helpful.